# Python or Ruby for webbased Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, artificial-intelligence, prolog

A new web application may require adding Artificial Intelligence (AI) in the future, e.g. using ProLog. I know it can be done from a Java environment, but I am wondering about the opportunities with modern web languages like Ruby or Python. The latter is considered to be "more scientific" (at least used in that environment), but using Google there seems to be a preliminary ProLog implementation for both.

Any suggestions on modern (open source) web languages (like Python or Ruby) in combination with AI?

Comment: AI is a huge field. If you want any meaningful answers you have to be specific.

Answer (score 7):

The selection of language is completely irrelevant, all other things being equal.

If you're trying to do X and there's a library for it in language Y and meshes well with your Web-based framework, then use it.

Without knowing more about what specific areas of AI you're interested in, the question is far too vague to be answered with any more specificity.

Comment: I wouldn't say irrelevant. Certain languages have larger AI/machine-learning userbases than others, and therefore will have more tools at your disposal.

Comment: I believe this is reflected in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If you like [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog), then check out [PySWIP](http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/). It integrates the declarative logic language Prolog with the procedural general purpose language Python, which lets you write webapps procedurally in Python as you are used to, but have an underlying relational database with Prolog.

Answer (score 0):

If you used [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) or [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) you can make use of the existing Java libraries and use either Ruby or Python for the web app. Rails works on JRuby and I have used it to write apps that reuse existing Java code. Not sure of which Python frameworks run on Jython.

Comment: JPype is another (arguably better) option. It's aim is to be a bridge to the JVM, so you can access Java libraries from CPython.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find [PyKE](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/) useful.

Edit:

> "Pyke introduces a form of Logic Programming (inspired by Prolog) to
>   the Python community by providing a knowledge-based inference engine
>   (expert system) written in 100% Python.
>
> Unlike Prolog, Pyke integrates with Python allowing you to invoke Pyke
>   from Python and intermingle Python statements and expressions within
>   your expert system rules."

For BiggAl, who is apparently too lazy to read the first two sentences on the linked page.

Comment: No real effort made here - some description of what this is would save those reading the effort of evaluating whether this is useful or not - I'll remove the downvote if explanation is given and even upvote if it's useful

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Scala (which is a bit functional and runs on the JVW) and the existing Lift framework for web-stuff.