# How to apply Machine Learning algorithm in PHP?

Tags: php, web-applications, machine-learning

If you are developing a ML project on PHP, is it logical to use PHP itself for ML algorithms (I guess it'll be slow) or what is the correct way of implementation of ML in such project. Do I need to bridge another language like Java with Mahout? If it is the case how can I bridge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632160/how-to-make-a-php-extension)

Comment: If you can find the routines you need in Java, use the PHP-Java Bridge component.

Comment: For interested: https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml

Answer (score 7):

The machine learning can be done best in Java and Python, because of availability of excellent libraries. You can always use PHP as web front-end, because it does that best. You could expose Java/Python program on HTTP and use PHP-CURL or use one of bridges mentioned above.
First off, determine the type of problem. From Wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) on Machine Learning:

1. Neural Networks
2. Expert Systems
3. Genetic Algorithm
4. Fuzzy Logic
5. Bayesian network

For Python, I know of [PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/), PyMC, Orage etc which are good.

Comment: PHP-ML is a great library for machine learning too!

Answer (score 6):

Don't start off by developing your code in PHP.

Take a look at the data sets first using something like Matlab or Octave. You should be able to get a feel for the data in less than 1 day.

This will help you understand the algorithms to use.

Re language, most of the stuff I've seen has used Java. Not sure whether you'd find as many established ML libraries in PHP.

See also:
[Which langauge should i use for Artificial intelligence on web projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050450/which-langauge-should-i-use-for-artificial-intelligence-on-web-projects)

Comment: +1 for not starting off in PHP, specific libraries are the way to go to develop algorithms. That being said, there *IS* a project to do ML in PHP https://github.com/gburtini/Learning-Library-for-PHP